# ATL control display image with Bitblt SRCAND not correct in word 2013

Tags: c++, ms-word, ms-office, activex, atl

I created a ATL project with following code:

```
LRESULT OnCreate(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
    const LONG_PTR exStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(GWL_EXSTYLE);
    SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
    return 0;
}

HRESULT OnDrawAdvanced(ATL_DRAWINFO& di)
{
    RECT& rc = *(RECT*)di.prcBounds;

    CImage imgx;
    imgx.Load(_T("C:\\image.jpg"));
    imgx.TransparentBlt
    imgx.StretchBlt(di.hdcDraw, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom, 0,0,imgx.GetWidth(),imgx.GetHeight(), SRCAND);

    return S_OK;
}
```

image.jpg here:

[image]

this works in ms-word2007

[image]

in ms-word2013, when I changed the wrapping style to "In front of text",it displays a grayed image.

[image]

why is that? and how to fix this. Thanks very much.

Comment: I can't help, directly, but I can tell you that Word's (Offices) graphics engine was changed massively in Office 2013. That might have something to do with what you're seeing.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Microsoft? They are really the only ones why know how their file formats "work".

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, Microsoft suggested contacting Microsoft support to raise an incident. but that cost $599 at least.